# char* to LPWSTR

Tags: c++, winapi

Прошу помочь в приведении типов.

> Ошибка: error C2664: 'LookupPrivilegeNameW' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'char *' to 'LPWSTR' в функции LookupPrivilegeName(), третий параметр.

Мне кажется я перепробовала все что можно, но ничего не получается.

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma hdrstop

/*LPWSTR CharToLPWSTR(LPCSTR char_string) 
{
    LPWSTR res;
    DWORD res_len = MultiByteToWideChar(1251, 0, char_string, -1, NULL, 0);
    res = (LPWSTR)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, (res_len + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR));
    MultiByteToWideChar(1251, 0, char_string, -1, res, res_len);
    return res;
}*/

int main()
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    LUID setcbnameValue;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkp;
    DWORD errcod;
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPCTSTR msgptr;

    UCHAR InfoBuffer[1000];
    PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES ptgPrivileges = (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)InfoBuffer;
    DWORD dwInfoBufferSize;
    DWORD dwPrivilegeNameSize;
    DWORD dwDisplayNameSize;
    UCHAR ucPrivilegeName[500];
    UCHAR ucDisplayName[500];
    DWORD dwLangId;
    UINT i;

    if(!OpenProcessToken( GetCurrentProcess(),
        TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
    {
        puts("OpenProcessToken");
        return;
    }

    GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenPrivileges, InfoBuffer,
        sizeof InfoBuffer, &dwInfoBufferSize);

    printf("Account privileges: \n\n");
    for(i = 0; i < ptgPrivileges->PrivilegeCount; i++)
    {
        dwPrivilegeNameSize = sizeof ucPrivilegeName;
        dwDisplayNameSize = sizeof ucDisplayName;
        LookupPrivilegeName(NULL, &ptgPrivileges->Privileges[i].Luid,
            (char *)ucPrivilegeName, &dwPrivilegeNameSize);
        /*LookupPrivilegeDisplayName(NULL, (char *)ucPrivilegeName,
            (char *)ucDisplayName, &dwDisplayNameSize, &dwLangId);*/
        printf("%s   (%s)\n", ucPrivilegeName);//, ucDisplayName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам же черным по белому пишут: функция принимает указатель на wchar_t, а вы ей указатель на char суете!

Answer (score 5):

В *WinApi* многие функции имеют две версии:

- одна для символов типа `char`
- другая для символов типа `wchar_t`

Названия таких функций отличаются последней буквой: `A` для `char`, `W` для `wchar_t`. Помимо этого имеется макрос, который в зависимости от настроек проекта (считай некой константы, заданной через `#define`) позволяет вызывать ту или иную функцию, не указывая суффикс `A`/`W` вовсе.

Т.о. если нужно всегда опираться на тип `char` используйте `A`-функцию, для `wchar_t` - `W`-функцию. В случае, когда хочется сделать универсальный вариант, используйте функцию без суффикса. Но тогда и типы переменных, используемых как аргументы подобных функций должны быть заданы неявно. Т.е. вместо `char` и `wchar_t` нужно использовать `TCHAR`, который развернётся в нужный тип в зависимости от настроек символьного типа проекта (по сути от того, определёна ли константа `_UNICODE`). Более подробно можно например почитать [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/164193/).

Answer (score 3):

Используйте ASCII-вариант функции, `LookupPrivilegeNameA()`.

Исходная функция `LookupPrivilegeName()` — это на самом деле макрос, разворачивающийся либо в ASCII, либо Unicode вариант в зависимости от флагов компиляции.

Из-за своей «двойственной» природы такие функции требуют и «двойственных» типов данных — [`LPTSTR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx#LPTSTR) для указателя на строку и [`TCHAR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx#TCHAR) + [`TEXT()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd374074(v=vs.85).aspx) для символа. При использовании же `char` или `wchar_t` необходимо использовать и конкретные версии функций, с суффиксами `A` и `W` соответственно.

Comment: Не имеет смысла в юникодной версии операционки работать с ANSI-строками, потому что преобразование в ANSI будет с возможными потерями.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы работаете с юникодной версией (а с какой ещё? 2017 год на дворе!), переходите на широкие юникодные строки.

Замените определение `ucPrivilegeName` на

```
WCHAR ucPrivilegeName[500];
```

При выводе юникодных строк используйте `wprintf` и т. д.