# FindWindowA не находит название окна на русском языке

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, qt5

Если `str` английская, вроде все нормально. А вот на русском не находит окно:

```
QString str = "Этот компьютер";
LPCSTR lstr = str.toStdString().c_str();
HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, lstr);
```

Comment: Используйте `FindWindowW`.

Comment: спс вроде работает

Answer (score 1):

Для узких `char` и широких `wchar_t` строк в *WinAPI* используются разные функции. Подробнее можно прочитать в [моём ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/627579/176217) на связанный вопрос: [char* to LPWSTR](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/627558/176217).

Здесь же происходит следующее: [`QString::toStdString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toStdString) преобразует строку `"Этот компьютер"`, которая хранится внутри `QString` как набор 16-битных символов (т.е. `QChar`) в последовательность символов `char` (1 байт) с помощью функции [`toUtf8`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toUtf8). А так как `FindWindowA` ждёт строку в однобайтовой (локальной) кодировке, то UTF-8 (мультибайтовая) строка для неё не подходит.

Наиболее правильным решением будет использование строк широких символов и функции [`QString:toStdWString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toStdWString).

```
QString str = "Этот компьютер";
LPWSTR lstr = str.toStdWString().c_str();
HWND hwnd = FindWindowW(NULL, lstr);
```

Хотя, вероятно, сработал бы и вариант с использованием локальной кодировки ([`QString::toLocal8Bit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toLocal8Bit)) .

```
QString str = "Этот компьютер";
LPCSTR lstr = str.toLocal8Bit().data();
HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, lstr);
```