# Ещё один "Cannot convert const char* to LPCWSTR"

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть самописная функция, лежащая в файле библиотеки, подключенном к главному:

```
HWND CreateEditor(
    TCHAR* tText,
    HWND hParent,
    POINT pCoords = {0, 0},
    SHAPE Size = {200, 50},
    DWORD dStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT)
{
    return CreateWindow("edit", tText, dStyle, pCoords.x, pCoords.y, Size.width, Size.height, hParent, (HMENU)NULL, hInstance, NULL);
}
```

В главном же файле объявлено:

```
#define _UNICODE
```

Компилятор ругается на 10ю строку так:

> "Cannot convert const char* to LPCWSTR for argument 2 to HWND__* CreateWindowExW(DWORD, LPCWSTR, LPCTWSTR, int, int, int, int, HWND, HMENUHINSTANCE, LPVOID)"

Пожалуйста, помогите.

Comment: А если ещё добавить `#define UNICODE` (без подчёркивания)?

Comment: @VladD Ошибуа не видоизменяется и не исчезает(

Comment: "edit" is char. Он должен быть заменен на wchar, когда UNICODE is defined - замените на _T("edit") тогда этот параметер будет менять тип в зависимости от настройки UNICODE

Comment: По сообщению об ошибке видно, что `CreateWindow` - это просто макрос, вызывающий `CreateWindowEx` со сдвигом параметров вправо на 1. То есть "аргумент 2" из сообщения об ошибке - это ваш аргумент 1, т.е. `"edit"`. Ну а дальше все очевидно. Почему вы пытаетесь передавать в качестве аргумента обычную строку `"edit"` если сами запросили W-версию функции?

Comment: @AnT в ошибке, кстати, `CreateWindowExW`, а очевидность сдвига без дополнительных знаний WinAPI, вряд ли будет очевидно. К тому же, при таких знаниях, я думаю, и вопрос бы не возник.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LPCWSTR` это синоним для `CONST WCHAR *`, об этом можно узнать на [странице](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx) msdn. В терминах натурального C++ это будет `const wchar_t *`. Чтобы строковый литерал был совместимым с упомянутым типом нужно добавить префикс `L`, т.е. в вашем случае использовать `L"edit"`. Можно ещё обойтись WinAPI макросом `_T`, который учитывает наличие юникодности проекта. В этом случае можно использовать запись `_T("edit")`.

Дополнительную информацию вы можете получить в связанном вопросе: [char* to LPWSTR](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/627558)

Comment: Не надо L"edit". L используется только при явных вызовах UNICODE-функций. Для CreateWindow правильный вариант - TEXT("edit") или _T("edit"), если подключен tchar.h

Comment: @mega: Нет. Это зависит от решения автора проекта. Если автор проекта сразу хочет пользоваться именно и только широкими символами - то никакого `_T` в коде и близко быть не должно. `_T` - только для проектов-трансфомеров. Намерения писать трансформер я в данном случае не вижу. Поэтому - именно `L"edit"`.

Comment: @AnT, по Вашей же логике, в Unicode-проекте не должно быть `CreateWindow` и прочих аналогичных макросов к API, сделанных исключительно для таких "проектов-трансфомеров". Пользуйтесь в таком случае функциями, подобными `CreateWindowW`, ни кто Вам слова не скажет.

Comment: @mega: А не надо "роботизировать" мою логику. Чисто ради более элегантного имени функции я могу выбрать `CreateWindow`, а не `CreateWindowW`. В этом есть смысл. А вот какой смысл в захламлении кода фичами `tchar.h` тогда, когда они совсем не нужны - я не вижу.

Comment: Это уже Ваше дело. На вкус и цвет товарищей нет. Мой первый комментарий к вашим предпочтениям отношения не имеет. Это общая практика.