# Создание папки с помощью переменной. c++

Tags: c++

сразу перейду к сути. Есть простой кусок кода: (`CreateDirectoryA("D:\\Somefolder", NULL);`). Мне нужно чтобы имя новой директории(ее путь) приходил из переменной, что-то на подобии этого. (`std::string dir = "D:\\Somefolder";
     CreateDirectoryA(dir, NULL);`).
Но ничего не выходит. И это для меня нонсенс. Подскажите возможные решения данной проблемы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Правильно вот так:

```
std::string dir = "D:\\Somefolder";
CreateDirectoryA(dir.c_str(), NULL);
```

Первый параметр у `CreateDirectoryA` - это С-строка, то есть `const char *`.

`std::string` автоматически в `const char *` не преобразуется. Чтобы получить из `std::string` *указатель* на строку, нужно вызвать метод `.c_str()`.

Comment: Как дополнение. 
`std::wstring dir = L"D:\\Somefolder";
CreateDirectory( dir.c_str(), NULL );`

Comment: @ArtemRachmaninov тогда уж не `std::wstring`, а `std::basic_string<TCHAR>`, чтобы учесть настройки проекта. Чуть подробнее [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/627579/176217).

Comment: @alexolut тогда уж - зачем нужны эти настройки проекта если в принципе правильно использовать unicode, так как windows и так работает на юникоде а VS по умолчанию создаёт юникод проекты.

Comment: @ArtemRachmaninov правильнее - не использовать Windows.