# C++ #define UNICODE

Tags: c++, winapi

Код:

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif 

#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
 switch(uMsg) {
  case WM_DESTROY:
   PostQuitMessage(0);
   return 0;
  case WM_PAINT: {
   PAINTSTRUCT ps;
   HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
   FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1));
   EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
   return 0;
  }
 }
 return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
 // Register the window class.
 const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"Sample Window Class";
 WNDCLASS wc = {};
 wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
 wc.hInstance = hInstance;
 wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
 RegisterClass(&wc);
 // Create the window.
 HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
  0,                              // Optional window styles.
  CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
  L"Learn to Program Windows",    // Window text
  WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style
                                // Size and position
  CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
  NULL,       // Parent window    
  NULL,       // Menu
  hInstance,  // Instance handle
  NULL        // Additional application data
 );

 if(hwnd == NULL) {
  return 0;
 }

 ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

 // Run the message loop.

 MSG msg = {};
 while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
  TranslateMessage(&msg);
  DispatchMessage(&msg);
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Вопросы:

1. Что делают препроцессорные директивы?
2. Что делает L перед string? (L"Sample Window Class";)
3. Можно ли без препроцессорных директив?

Comment: Переводит все на широкие символы включая функции из API.Посмотрите tchar.h - вот для него по сути это и есть.

Comment: [широкие символы!](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB) :)

Comment: Я к тому, что код у вас в примере в любом случае не рабочий, а `UNICODE` не играет в нем совершенно никакой роли. О предназначении макросов `UNICODE` и `_UNICODE` в Windows SDK можно [почитать на MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Intl/unicode-in-the-windows-api)

Comment: @MikeWaters Нет, он не работает ни в каком случае. Сами же выложили лог с ошибками и картинку с красными подчеркиваниями.

Comment: @VTT добавил полный код, поправил вопрос

Comment: Получается директивы переводят все в wchar_t, L делает из обычных 8 bit - 16 bit, т.е делает wchar_t?

Comment: Отлично :) именно так! для совместимости есть tchar.h - посмотрите этот файл. Он переключает с char на wchar_t в зависимости от макроса UNICODE

Comment: `L` служит для объявления литералов `wchar_t`, но никак не зависит от макроса `UNICODE`. От `UNICODE` зависят макросы типа `TCHAR` или `GetMessage`. Но их использовать не стоит, а вместо них следует прямо вызывать широкие варианты функций (`GetMessageW` и т.п.). И вообще, вся канитель с макросом `UNICODE` бала нужна для облегчения портирования приложений pre windows 98.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Большинство функций WinAPI существуют в двух вариантах: ANSI (использующие текущую кодовую страницу системы) и Unicode. Эти варианты называются наборами символов (character sets). Если открыть заголовочные файлы Windows SDK, можно увидеть, что функции в них объявлены так:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define CreateFile  CreateFileW
#else
#define CreateFile  CreateFileA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

Использование символа препроцессора UNICODE позволяет писать код, не привязываясь к определенному набору символов: добавляя или убирая его определение, можно легко переключиться с одного на другой. Эта функциональность была полезна во времена, когда нужно было собирать приложения как под Windows 9x, не поддерживающую Unicode, так и под Windows XP. Определить символ препроцессора можно не только из кода, но и параметром компилятора (например, ключ /D в Visual C++), что позволяло иметь одинаковый код проекта и собирать его в студии разными конфигурациями под разные ОС.

Кроме того, в Visual C++ есть заголовочный файл tchar.h, который использует похожий механизм для функций стандартной библиотеки, но он использует другой символ препроцессора - `_UNICODE`.

Comment: [Хех](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/627579/176217)

Comment: @alexolut, [ага](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/627576/208074)