# Включение Unicode при использовании WinAPI

Tags: c, windows, winapi, unicode

Для включения *режима Юникода* в **WinAPI** требуется два определения:

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE
```

Подскажите, зачем нужно два определения, чем они отличаются и бывают ли ситуации, когда нужно одно, но не другое?

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/875087/240512

Comment: Не то. Меня интересует, зачем два определения **UNICODE** и **_UNICODE**, чем они отличаются?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UNICODE` используется заголовочными файлами Windows, а `_UNICODE` - заголовочными файлами C-runtime и MFC.